# Failed to execute goal on project Siafu: Could not resolve dependencies for project Siafu:Siafu:jar:1.0.6-SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, git, maven

```
Siafu is a context simulator         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] Reactor Summary:
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] MavenParent ........................................ SUCCESS [  0.004 s]
        [INFO] Siafu Simulator .................................... FAILURE [01:27 min]
        [INFO] Siafu datatypes library ............................ SKIPPED
        [INFO] Simulation-Glasgow ................................. SKIPPED
        [INFO] Simulation-Leimen .................................. SKIPPED
        [INFO] Simulation-Office .................................. SKIPPED
        [INFO] Simulation-Testland ................................ SKIPPED
        [INFO] Simulation-Valencia ................................ SKIPPED
        [INFO] Simulations ........................................ SKIPPED
        [INFO] SiafuAggregator .................................... SKIPPED
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] Total time: 01:27 min
        [INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-24T15:45:12+08:00
        [INFO] Final Memory: 10M/91M
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Siafu: Could not resolve dependencies for project Siafu:Siafu:jar:1.0.6-SNAPSHOT: 
Failed to collect dependencies at org.eclipse.swt:org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86:jar:3.8: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.eclipse.swt:org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86:jar:3.8: 
Could not transfer artifact org.eclipse.swt:org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86:pom:3.8 from/to swt-repo (https://swt-repo.googlecode.com/svn/repo/): Network is unreachable (connect failed) -> [Help 1]
            [ERROR] 
            [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
            [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
            [ERROR] 
            [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
            [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
            [ERROR] 
            [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
            [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf
```

Please give me some help to solve this problem,thanks!

Comment: The repository was moved to [github](https://github.com/maven-eclipse/swt-repo)

Comment: Thanks for your reply